# MC Comix doesn't seem to open CBR files

Tags: files

I've installed MC Comix on Ubuntu 20.0. When I try to open a CBR file, it doesn't recognise it, and the list of "all files" doesn't contain CBR, which I'd have thought essential for a comic reader. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

When replying, please bear in mind that I'm a complete novice who's just installed Ubuntu and knows nothing about coding. Thanks for taking the time to look at this, and sorry about the wrong tag. I couldn't upload the question without one, but anything that seemed relevant to me wasn't accepted.

Frank Plowright

Comment: How did you installed MComix? If snap (typically) then it needs to be given permissions to read from outside /home/user and even so it'll at most access files under /media or /mnt as well. This is likely the problem but please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Hello. A good place to start is a valid version number. There is no version 20.0 of Ubuntu.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, I just installed it and it unpacked, but this was a few weeks ago and I only looked at it this week. I'm not sure what you mean by editing the question. Do you mean changing it to include your information? David - as it seems to make a difference, I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, not 20.00.